# Errno 61 Connection refused when using Selenium XPath on Yahoo Finance dynamic content

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I run the following code to get Analyst Rating (dynamic content on the right of stock page - picture attached) [Analyst Recommendation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2c7o.png):

```
# Import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

link_base = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/'
stock_link = link_base + 'RYAAY' + '?p=' + 'RYAAY'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(stock_link)
timeout = 10
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col2-6-QuoteModule-Proxy"]/div/section/a/h2/span')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    driver.quit()

analyst_rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Col2-6-QuoteModule-Proxy"]/div/section/div/div/div')
print (analyst_rating.text)
driver.quit()
```

In return I am getting Connection Refused Errno 61. The strangest thing is that this kept giving me an error. Then I restarted PyCharm, and it produced the desired number "2", but only once. It never worked again, and it's been hours. What could possibly be happening here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Timed out waiting for page to load
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikolaysitnikov/Desktop/google-python-exercises/Stocks scrape/yahoo_unit.py", line 29, in <module>
    analyst_rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Col2-6-QuoteModule-Proxy"]/div/section/div/div/div')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 843, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 306, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 487, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is being thrown because there is a networking problem between your machine and the webserver you are trying to access. If I had to guess at what could be the problem, I'd say your firewall is stopping selenium's request from going through. Look for firewall access prompts in your machine's settings. If there are none, try reinstalling chromeriver.

If you're trying to do any reliable web scraping, I would suggest switching to [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). Selenium is good for a lot of things, but not scraping sadly.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I figured it out. I was actually connecting fine. Turns out the elements were not appearing until scrolled down to. So I had to use Selenium to scroll down the page and everything worked.